# R ggplot2: modify the graph results shown due a pattern

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code and graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(cod= c(202101,202101,202101,202101,202102,202102,202102,202102,202103,202103,202103,202103,202104,202104,202104,202104),
                 val= c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                 porc= c(0.01,0.03,0.06,0.07,0,0.04,0.07,0.07,0.02,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02)
                 
)

dt %>% 
  mutate(cod= as.character(cod)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=val,y=porc))+
  geom_line(aes(color=cod))+
  geom_point(aes(color=cod))
```

[image]

I want to modify the results on the graph by the following rule:
-max code (202104 on the example): don't modify
-max code -1 (2020103 on the example): show all the results less the last one
-max code -2 (2020102 on the example): show all the results less the last two
-and so on

So, my final result should be something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can goup the variables by `cod` and then remove the duplicated values in `porc`

```
dt %>%
mutate(cod= as.character(cod)) %>% 
group_by(cod) %>% 
distinct(porc, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=val,y=porc))+
geom_line(aes(color=cod))+
geom_point(aes(color=cod))
```

[image]

Comment: you deserve an upvote just for having understood that question.